# Price issue with move element in xml file

Tags: magento2, layout

**catalog_product_view_type_grouped.xml**

I have assign configurable product in group product and price is showing properly for configurable product's swatch option.

But when i write below script to move "product-add-form" near page bottom in this XML file after that different price is showing.

**Before Price:**

[image]

```
<move element="product.info" destination="page.bottom" before="-"/>
```

**After Price:**

[image]

Comment: can you upload image properly?

Comment: can you share catalog_product_view_type_grouped.xml file?